# How to change place of field value in mysqli using php?

Tags: php, mysqli

In my database I have a table like this:

```
id  |  name
==================
1     | day sunny
------------------
2     | day windy
------------------
3     | cloudy night
------------------
4     |rainy outside day
-----------------
```

How can I print in program that name would be 
Sunny day, Windy day, Cloudy night (this I have to leave like this because its written in order that I want) and Rainy day outside ? It has to started with upper letter, and I cant save it into table just print in my program?

Here is my code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shop') or die ("Fail");
$sql="select *  from products";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $names = explode(" ", $row["name"]); 
           echo ucfirst(strtolower($names[1]." ".$names[0]." ".$names[2]."<br>" ));
        }
     }
```

It gives me almost exactly what I need but not 100%. 
Help me thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Sorry but we aren't here to code you something. We are here to help you if you have questions or issues with your code. Did you already try to code something, so we can see where you have issues and where we can help you? :)

Comment: Please share _your_ code. Questions should include a [mcve]. Show us what you have tried so far so that we might be able to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1 ),
    ' ',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( name, ' ', 1 )
    ) 
  AS Name FROM table_name
```

Result

```
-------------
 sunny day 
-------------
 windy day
-------------
 cloudy night
-------------
```

Here you can go, use the PHP ucfirst to make first letter capital case:-

```
SELECT name,
(
 CASE
     WHEN 
         INSTR(name, 'day') > 0 AND (LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) + 1) < 3
THEN
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1 ),
        ' ',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1 )
    )
WHEN
    INSTR(name, 'day') > 0 AND (LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) + 1) > 2
THEN
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1),' ','day'),
        ' ',
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -2),'day','')
    )
ELSE 
    name
END) AS Name
FROM tablename
```

Result: -

```
-----------
 sunny day
-----------
 windy day
-----------
 cloudy night
-----------
 rainy day outside
-----------
```

Try following inside PHP while loop:-

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //$rows[] = ucfirst($row['Name']);
        echo ucfirst($row['Name']);echo '<br/>';
     }
   }
```

Full PHP Code:-

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123123','stackoverflow') or die ("Fail");
$sql  = "SELECT name,
(
 CASE
     WHEN 
         INSTR(name, 'day') > 0 AND (LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) + 1) < 3
 THEN
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1 ),
        ' ',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1 )
    )
WHEN
    INSTR(name, 'day') > 0 AND (LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')) + 1) > 2
THEN
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1),' ','day'),
        ' ',
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -2),'day','')
    )
ELSE 
    name
END) AS Name
FROM tablename";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows   = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = ucfirst($row['Name']);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
  [0] => Sunny day
  [1] => Windy day
  [2] => Cloudy night
  [3] => Rainy day outside 
)
```

Comment: But if I have more then 2 words?

Comment: Please clear your questions what output you are looking

Comment: How can I print in program that name would be Sunny day, Windy day, Cloudy night (this I have to leave like this because its written in order that I want) and Rainy day outside ?

Comment: do you know how to do it with PHP logic?

Comment: try echo ucfirst(row['Name']) inside while loop

Comment: Full working PHP Code code has been posted under "Full PHP Code"

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
     $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = '';
     $dbname = 'example';
     $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

     if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
     }
     echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
     $sql = 'SELECT name FROM example_table';
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $names = explode(" ", $row["name"]);
           echo ucfirst($names[1])." ".$names[0] "<br>";
        }
     } else {
        echo "0 results";
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thank you it helps me :) But if I have on the same table name: cloudy night. and I want to leave it like this but change others name , how can I do it?

Comment: then you can have a if inside that while loop to just exclude that 'cloudy night' string